# What will be the query for fetching all the records from left table and matching records from the right tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What will be the query for fetching all the records from left table and matching records from the right tables?

Tables:

**properties:**

```
id cid property_name
1   1   Property1
2   1   Property2
3   1   Property3
4   1   Property4
```

**property_medias:**

```
id cid property_id media_file_id
1   1  1           1
2   1  1           2
3   1  1           4
4   1  2           5
5   1  2           6
```

**media_files**

```
id cid media_alt
1   1  NULL
2   1  pqr
3   1  NULL
4   1  ttt
5   1  NULL
6   1  NULL
```

**Expected Output:**

```
id  cid property_name media_alt
1   1   Property1      YES
2   1   Property2      NO
3   1   Property3       -
4   1   Property4       -
```

**Explanation of output:**
Property1 is having atleast one record having media_alt IS NOT NULL hence media_alt is 'YES'
Property2 is having all the records NULL for media_alt hence media_alt is 'NO'
Property3 and Property4 are not having any media associated with it hence media_alt is '-'.

**I tried with this query but it is giving me duplicate records of properties.**

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.property_name, mf.media_alt
FROM
properties AS p
JOIN property_medias pm ON ( pm.property_id = p.id AND pm.cid = p.cid)
JOIN media_files mf ON ( mf.id = pm.media_file_id AND mf.cid = pm.cid )
WHERE
p.cid  = 1
ORDER BY p.property_name
```

**Please help me in the right direction.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.property_name,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(mf.media_alt) > 0 THEN 'YES'
             WHEN COUNT(mf.cid) > 0 THEN 'NO'
             ELSE '-'
        END) as media_alt
FROM properties p LEFT JOIN
     property_medias pm
     ON pm.property_id = p.id AND pm.cid = p.cid LEFT JOIN
     media_files mf
     ON mf.id = pm.media_file_id AND mf.cid = pm.cid
WHERE p.cid = 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.property_name;
```

The first  `COUNT()` is determining if any of the column values are not `NULL`.  The second is determining if there are any matches.

You could also phrase this using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.property_name,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM property_medias pm LEFT JOIN
                               media_files mf
                               ON mf.id = pm.media_file_id AND mf.cid = pm.cid
                          WHERE pm.property_id = p.id AND
                                pm.cid = p.cid AND
                                mf.media_alt IS NOT NULL
                         )
             THEN 'YES'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM property_medias pm 
                          WHERE pm.property_id = p.id AND
                                pm.cid = p.cid
                         )
             THEN 'NO'
             ELSE '-'
        END) as media_alt
FROM properties p        
WHERE p.cid = 1;
```

This saves the outer aggregation, but may not have any performance advantage in Postgres.

Comment: This answer is a somewhat positive direction towards the solution of the main/original problem I have. One question if I have three/four more tables like `property_medias` having `media_file_id` field and `property_id` in it, THEN will it be possible to get the same format of results? Actually I am trying to get all the images having empty alt attributes that images are referenced in different tables.

Comment: Also, I have doubt on `WHEN COUNT(mf.cid) > 0 THEN 'NO'` in your first query will it get me expected records THAT IS 'property having no image with alt attribute ( all the images for the property are with empty alt ) ?

Comment: @VBMali . . . (1) If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question.  This answers the question that you asked here.  (2) Any matches are already captured by the `'YES'` logic.  By itself that condition is not sufficient, but it follows other logic.